# XSLT concat counter with a field name to make it dynamic

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

I am working on generating an xml using the following xslt. What I want to do is to iterate and then set the name of the field dynamically based on the counter.

My current xslt looks something like this, but clearly I am missing something

```
<xsl:for-each select="list1">   
     <field name="tagName">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="something != 'null'">
                <value><xsl:value-of select="something" /></value>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <value></value>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </field>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What I want is that the field Name would be something like tagName1, tagName2 etc.

I tried using the following

```
 <field name=concat('tagName', position())>
```

However that did not work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Think twice before you do that: it makes it difficult to process the result. Consider using an *attribute* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the source XML looks like, so I'm guessing here.

Assuming this is the source:

```
<list1>
  <tag>foo</tag>
  <tag>bar</tag>
  <tag>baz</tag>
</list1>
```

Then using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/list1">
  <xsl:for-each select="tag">   
    <field name="{concat('tag', position(), text())}"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Will return this:

```
<field name="tag1foo"/>
<field name="tag2bar"/>
<field name="tag3baz"/>
```

Is this close to what you wanted?

Comment: You could also do `<field name="tag{position()}{text()}"/>`.

Comment: Thank you so much @fafl ! That is exactly what I wanted